Servlet how to send response redirect with body data?
Trying to redirect with a body message?
response.sendRedirect(url);
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write("some message");
write.close();

and
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write("some message");
response.sendRedirect(url);
write.close();

In both cases, the response body received by http client is empty.
No error messages.
Response body for 302 is not forbidden.
HTTP 302 Redirect - is a message-body needed?

Indeed, according to its javadoc, the HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect() "clears the buffer", i.e. it clears any data written to the response body.
You'll need to manually set the Location header and the status code instead.
response.setHeader("Location", url);
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.getWriter().write("some message");

Noted should be that explicitly closing the response body is unnecessary. The container will already take care of it. See also Should I close the servlet outputstream?
